Convert value with a type to value of another type in Kotlin generically
I have a map with pairs of KType to a value in String, and I wish to convert those values to the type of KType in its pair(for example, convert "123" to an Int with the value 123).
Knowing that the value can always be converted to the KType in its pair since the map is built that way, how can I accomplish this in "generic" terms? Meaning, not creating for example a switch statement or similar for every type imaginable. Would this be possible?
// Do something to the values of each pair that converts them to the type in their pairing
val map = mapOf(kotlin.Boolean to "true", kotlin.Int to "123", kotlin.String to "hello")

 // "true" would become true
 // "123" would become 123
 // "hello" would stay as a String with the value "hello"


Sorry if my explanation isn't very clear.

How would you like to convert these values without writing the conversion part? How the Kotlin would know what you mean by converting? If the input type is always String, then many basic types have the valueOf function - you can utilize it. But there is no general meaning of converting one type to another type. Converting is always a "custom" operation.

My idea would be if there was something already built-in to Kotlin that could do that, or if there was a way to typecast it since I already have the type I want. It's likely that I'm approaching this all wrong, I'm not very experienced with Kotlin.

Casting is a different operation - it changes the type as seen by the compiler if the value is already of the target type. It doesn't really convert anything. Again, the only "standard" solution that comes to my mind is if we convert a String to basic types likes integers, etc.,and we target JVM, then by a convention, Java stdlib provides methods like Integer.valueOf. And there's toString for the opposite direction.

Are you coming from a JS background? It’s unusual to use reflection at all unless you’re building a library that does the kinds of conversions you’re describing between classes and strings.

I'm aware of it but not specifically, what I've asked is basically a simplified version of part of an assignment I have to do.

There is not a generic way to do this.  There are, for example, many ways to convert between integers and strings -- hexadecimal, for example.

Meaning, not creating for example a switch statement or similar for every type imaginable.

You will have to do this.
